# certificate import selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, certificate

Before running selenium there is a requirement that a certain certificate needs to be imported. On importing the same the execution starts as expected.

But each and everytime the execution re-starts (a new test suite is run), the certificate is no longer present in Firefox and hence fails as the certificate is not imported.

Is there any setting in selenium that will prevent the certificate from being unimported before the execution starts everytime/

-S

Comment: Show some code please. How do you tell `firefox` to have a certificate ready?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Firefox profile, import all your certificate in that profile and then use that profile while instantiating Firefox webdriver instance.

To create new Firefox profile refer [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_creating-a-profile).

**Once you import your certificate to newly created profile**, use below code to create Firefox webdriver instance:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = profile.getProfile("your_profile_name");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to setup a FireFox profile in Selenium.  You can setup a specific profile to use as @Surya mentioned above, or you can set setAcceptUntrustedCertificates to true for your profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Other methods that I've seen using a RemoteWebDriver involve wrapping your profile in DesiredCapabilities which also has a flag for accepting SSL certificates:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Without seeing how you've setup your profile, we're only taking shots in the dark.  Hopefully one of these suggestions works for you.